# 3D model looks black in render

Tags: modeling, rendering, camera, lighting

I'm trying to take a screenshot of a 3D model and it looks good in the viewport but when I go to take a render it looks way different. I was wondering if someone could help me figure out what's going on.

This is more or less the code I'm using to set up the screenshot

```
# add camera to scene
camera_data = bpy.data.cameras.new(name='Camera')
camera_object = bpy.data.objects.new('Camera', camera_data)
bpy.context.scene.collection.objects.link(camera_object)

camera_object.location = (-3.7271888256073, -6.519496917724609, 1.7946083545684814)
camera_object.rotation_euler.x = 1.335000991821289 
camera_object.rotation_euler.y = -0.014755947515368462
camera_object.rotation_euler.z = -0.45238134264945984

# add light source to scene
lamp_data = bpy.data.lights.new(name="New Lamp", type='SUN')
lamp_object = bpy.data.objects.new(name="New Lamp", object_data=lamp_data)
bpy.context.scene.collection.objects.link(lamp_object)
lamp_object.location = (0, -2.0, 2.0)
lamp_object.rotation_euler.x = 0.7458062767982483

# take screenshot with camera
bpy.context.scene.camera = camera_object
print('Set camera %s' % camera_object.name )
file = os.path.join(rimg.replace(".png","_render") )
bpy.context.scene.render.filepath = file
bpy.ops.render.render( write_still=True )
```

[image]

Comment: It's difficult to tell, but it looks like your render settings and render preview are using different lights.  In particular, your render looks like the film settings are high contrast.

Comment: Hm, there is some emission on the material of the glasses, which is why I think the color shows up. The frame material should otherwise be reflective.

Comment: a screenshot of the outliner with everything expanded and another of the render properties with the film panel expanded might help.

Comment: are you using compositing by any chance?

Comment: Thank you both for the suggestions. I was able to fix it by setting up an environment / adding an hdri to the scene.

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded an example HDRI here: https://polyhaven.com/hdris

Added to the world like in the image and the renders come out like in the viewport

[image]